# How to resume a thread suspended by sigwaitinfo/sigwait? How to check for signal queue?

Tags: c, multithreading, signals

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2

sem_t mutex;

pthread_t tid[NUM_THREADS];

void *thr_generator();
void *thr_handler();

int main(){
    sem_init(&mutex,0,1);   

    pthread_create(&tid[1],NULL,thr_handler,NULL);
    pthread_create(&tid[0],NULL,thr_generator,NULL);

    int i;
    for(i=0;i<2;i++){
        pthread_join(tid[i],NULL);
    }

    sem_destroy(&mutex);
}

void *thr_generator(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        pthread_kill(tid[1],SIGUSR1);
        sleep(1);
    }
}

void *thr_handler(){
    sigset_t sig_set;
    sigemptyset(&sig_set);

    int i;
    int sig;
    sigaddset(&sig_set,SIGUSR1);
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK,&sig_set,NULL);
    while(1){
        printf("Waiting on a signal...\n");



        if((i=(sigwaitinfo(&sig_set,NULL)))==10){
            printf("signal received\n");

        }
        else{
            printf("The set is empty\n");
            exit(0);
            //break;
        }


        printf("%d\n",i);

    }
    pthread_sigmask(SIG_UNBLOCK,&sig_set,NULL);

}
```

Above is my entire test code for reference.

For testing purpose, I created 2 threads, in which one send SIGUSR1 to the other, which handles the signal.

My question is regarding specifically the thr_handler function.

When I compile this code and run it, I would get the output of

```
Waiting on a signal...
signal received
.
.    (meaning the same output repeats x number of times according to the generator   loop)
.

Waiting on a signal...  (stuck here)
```

---

If my understanding is correct, sigwaitinfo() function inside thr_handler is suspending the handling thread and there is no way to resume the thread unless another signal is received by it. What can I do so that I can check to see if the signal queue is empty and break out of the loop? Is there a way to check to see if the queue of signals is empty?

Also, initially, I planned to use sleep() on some random number between .01 and .1 in every iteration of generator loop. Is this enough of a delay so that all signals are received by the handler thread? When I was testing my code using a generator loop of 10000, it seemed to me that the handler only received about 100 or less signals according to the output.

Answer (score 0):

In this part of your code

```
if((i=(sigwaitinfo(&sig_set,NULL)))==10){
            printf("signal received\n");

        }
```

You should check to see which signal is being sent, SIGUSR1
so it would be:

```
 if(sigwaitinfo(&sig_set,NULL) == SIGUSR1){
                printf("signal received\n");
            }
```

You have sent 10 signals, therefore 10 SIGUSR1 will be received.
You have only one thread running the handler which is safe. However, if later you want to generate more than one thread to run the handler, there will be synchronization problems and more code will be needed.